# Why does my external HDD unmount itself?

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I've got an external HDD connected to my PC via USB 2.0.
When I mount the HDD after booting, everything works in the first few minutes.

But when I start copying files from my internal to the external HDD, after a few minutes my external HDD unmounts and disappers in the device-list. It's not visible anywhere in my system although its connected. So i can't mount it again.

To use it again I have to unplug it (usually only the USB, but sometimes also the Power-Connection) and plug it in again after a few minutes. But when I start copying files again, the sme happens.

What is wrong with my PC or my setup? Is it a Bug of Ubuntu (that maybe fixed) or is my HDD broken?

Comment: You might try reformatting the drive. No idea why this works but it did for me. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/546062/198090).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a problem with your external HDD. It may not be the HDD itself - it may just be the enclosure failing. If possible, you should try either putting the drive in a different external enclosure or connecting it internally to a computer and see if it works.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to open the HDD without destroying the enclosure. It does not show any screws.

Comment: They often just have plastic clips (that are quite hard to unclip). You should see if there is a user manual for your model of external hard drive online (there usually is).

Your other option is to connect the drive to a different computer and see if you get the same problems - if so, then it's definitely an issue with either the drive or enclosure.

Comment: By now i bought a new HDD for my own data security (you know they arent so expensive)