# My external hard drive keeps unmounting and remounting itself

Tags: mount, external-hdd, automount

I have a Seagate 500 GB desktop external drive. When I plug the drive in through USB 2.0, it immediately auto-mounts and functions for about 1 minute before unmounting itself. After a few more minutes it will auto-mount again and the process repeats.

Is my drive bad or is there any hope that I can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried manually mounting the drive? Does the problem persist?

Comment: Mounting manually also quickly disconnected. I've since taken the hard drive out of it's original case and put it in a new enclosure. It has now been working flawlessly for about 2 months.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I've been having a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, this is related to USB Power Management Problems: not enough power on the USB. Then it is solved by:

- reduce the power consuming: make a static, horizontal position of your External Hard Drive;
- increase the power providing: use another usb port or another USB cabel;
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some people using Mac OSX that have had similar problems (see [here](https://superuser.com/q/699948/279786) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5486533?start=0&tstart=0)).

The solution that works for many of them (including me) was to just reformat the drive. Since your drive only stays mounted for a short time you will have to do the reformatting quickly.

You can do this with a tool such as `gparted`, but **be careful** you can lose data if you don't know what you are doing.

**EDIT:**
This worked for about a week. I have since taken the bare hard drive out of the case and placed it in this new [enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817173043). Things seem to be working so hopefully it was just a problem with the case.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I plugged my external Seagate drive into what appeared to be a USB 3.0 port on the front of my case.  Despite having a blue connector, apparently it was not actually a USB 3.0 port.  I seem to have fixed the problem by plugging the drive into one of the real USB 3.0 ports on the back of my computer.